# How does Google's Traffic Estimator calculate the "Estimated Avg. CPC"?

Tags: traffic, google-workspace, google-ads

I use Google's [Traffic Estimator](https://adwords.google.com/o/Targeting/Explorer?__c=3148491556&__u=1908280996&__o=te&ideaRequestType=KEYWORD_STATS#search.none) to calculate the Estimated Average Cost Per Click.

I use the following filters:

```
Locations: Australia
Languages: English
```

and the following phrase `air conditioner melbourne`.

When I use `Max CPC = $100`, the result is: `AU$6.08`.

But, when I use `Max CPC = $10`, the result is: `AU$3.87`.

Why is this difference?

Answer (score 3):

The "Max CPC" field is the maximum you wish to pay per click. If you enter a Max CPC of $100 then you will never pay more than $100 per click, so the average will always be less than $100 - in this case $6.08.

However, restricting it to $10 Max CPC means you're cutting out all the clicks from $10 to $100, therefore the average CPC will be less.

Quick example: two companies by ads at $20 per click and $2 per click respectively. The Average CPC here is $11. Now, if your Max CPC was $10 then the $20 ad is ignored, meaning the new average is just $2.

Comment: Is there any way to know the number of ads that participate in the average calculation (e.g. 2 ads in your example)?

Comment: Not that I know of, sorry.

Comment: Regarding your example: If put `Max CPC = $10`, and I get `Estimated Avg. CPC = $2`, should I assume that if I pay $2 per click Google will place my ad in the first position? I thought that if someone pays more than me (like $20 in the example), its ad will be above mine. What am I missing?

Comment: Maybe you could also help me with this related question: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/22378

Answer (score 1):

Basically you can use the formula for calculating the average cpc 
average cpc= (ad rank/quality score)+ estimated first page bid
max cpc=$100
you find the quality score of that keyword
estimated first page bid =$.01
then you can calculate average cpc of that keyword