# How does Google's Traffic Estimator calculates the "Estimated Avg. CPC"?

Tags: google

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does Google's Traffic Estimator calculate the “Estimated Avg. CPC”?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/22301/how-does-googles-traffic-estimator-calculate-the-estimated-avg-cpc)

I use Google's [Traffic Estimator](https://adwords.google.com/o/Targeting/Explorer?__c=3148491556&__u=1908280996&__o=te&ideaRequestType=KEYWORD_STATS#search.none) to calculate the Estimated Average Cost Per Click.

I use the following filters:

```
Locations: Australia
Languages: English
```

and the following phrase `air conditioner melbourne`.

When I use `Max CPC = $100`, the result is: `AU$6.08`.

But, when I use `Max CPC = $10`, the result is: `AU$3.87`.

Why is this difference?